# Can X-ray scanners damage mobile SIM cards?

Tags: radiation

My bag passes through an X-ray scanner every day.  They insist that our mobile phones need to be in the bag as well.

I have heard from a person that continuous scanning damages the phone's SIM card. Is this true?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8580/can-airport-x-ray-machines-scramble-kindle-screens

Comment: Who was this person you heard it from? Just some person you met on a plane? Or someone with knowledge of the claim in question?

Comment: "I heard from a person" isn't a [notable claim](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable).